# TinyMCE 3.4 image upload tool other than iBrowser

Tags: upload, tinymce

I've looked for this for a bit, but it seems there is no working plugin for uploading photos/images through [TinyMCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyMCE), apart from MCImageManager that you have to pay for it.

Is there a plugin working for this purpose with the latest TinyMCE? I've tried [iBrowser](http://seoroot.com/blog/computing/programming/tinymce-ibrowser-plugin.html), but that didn't do the trick.

That said, instead of asking another question, is there another handy TinyMCE plugin that enhance its use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came across a post in TinyMCE's forum, ["Image Manager Plugin for free"](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=26252).

After trying out the 'images' plugin mentioned in the second post, it worked.

It's recommended since it is easy to implement and there is a nice interface where you can create,delete folders, upload one or multiple photos.

#### Downside

No documentation exists at all but it is relatively easy to implement after having a look through the plugins folders.

Comment: i added the link at the top, just bellow the question.

Comment: showing error like -- Undefined index JPG support! Do you have any idea?

Comment: solved it by using JPEG rather than JPG to find the index in Image_Toolbox.class.php on line 186.